# what is the right selector for extracting the links of products?

Tags: r, web-scraping, css-selectors

I want to scrape the product links (href) in this webpage.
https://www.artfinder.com/editors-picks/theme/amazing-techniques/blurred-lines/#/

I am working with r and cannot figure out what is the right selector to write in the html_nodes().
I tried ".fit-in" , "a.af-place.fit-in" and they won't give the links.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of this page does not work with selectors in `rvest`. If you use something like Chrome's developer tools, you can examine the resources used by the page and it turns out there is an API that returns the data in JSON format.

So, one way of getting the data you need (which will need a little more tidying up) would be...

```
library(jsonlite)
prod_url <- "https://www.artfinder.com/api/theme/amazing-techniques/blurred-lines/products/?page=1&paginate=1000&sort=best_match&limit=1000"
prods <- fromJSON(prod_url)$results
```

This returns a dataframe with lots of information, including a column containing the urls.

Comment: woah! that's so good! but may I ask how to find the adjusted link?

Comment: In Chrome I loaded the first URL, right clicked on a product and went to "inspect", clicked "Network" and reloaded the page, then went to "Sources", and searched for "URBAN BLUR" (text from one of the products). This came up with one result (clearly in JSON format), which I clicked on, which took me to the API address. I adjusted the parameters in order to load all products rather than just 12 (the default).